# Merge 2 objects with same enum results in never

Tags: typescript

How can I merge both of the object types when there is an enum with 2 names:

```
enum e1 {
  bo = 'bo',
}

enum e2 {
  bo = 'bo',
}

type a1 = {
  a: e1
  b: number
}
type a2 = {
  a: e2
  c: string
}

type a12 = a1 & a2

// expected: { a: e1 (or e2), b: number, c: string }
// actual: never
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=17&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBMCMUG8BQUoCMD2UC8UDkmeANEgL5JKiQwBMiK6WuBGxZFALgJ4AOwUAQ3i5kqAQC4YsBmkngIaYACd23PoLoiGE2gwDGkgM4clASxABzdkjX8hmwfABkGigHo3MAB589HYAAmkgiCknBQABQYSrQAlETocpCKSgkGUMZmllDkHoJ+YAIANnLAAG7KQA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript assigned the type `never` to `a12` as types of `a1` and `a2` aren't intersecting i.e. `a` can never be `e1` and `e2` at the same time. Type of `a` in `a1` is Enum `e1`, while in `a2` it's Enum `e2`. It would have the same result if we define types `a1` and `a2` like this:

```
type a1 = {
  a: 1
  b: number
}
type a2 = {
  a: 2
  c: string
}

type a12 = a1 & a2    //never
```

since types of `a` in `a1` and `a2` are non-intersecting. To have the expected type, you can do:

```
type a12 = Omit<a1, 'a'> & Omit<a2, 'a'> | { a: e1 | e2 };
```

Comment: Thank you. But as far as my eyes can see, `e1` and `e2` has same keys and values. so aren't they the same for the compailer?

Comment: No. Just do a simple check. `console.log(e1 === e2)`.

Comment: `console.log(e1 === e2)` has almost no bearing on whether `typeof e1` and `typeof e2` are the same for the compiler.  I mean, `interface Foo {a: number}; const f1: Foo = {a: 0}; const f2: Foo = {a: 0}; console.log(f1 === f2);` produces `false` but `f1` and `f2` have the same type.

Comment: The real reason you can't intersect enums this way is because [enums are one of the few places in TS where types are somewhat *nominal*](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping#using-enums), and the intersection of two distinct named enum types will be `never` because of this.